# c#:String to integer conversion?

Tags: c#

I have the string in format of Rs.2, 50,000. Now I want to read the string value as 250000 and insert into database (let assume that Rs 2,50,000 coming from third party like web services, wcf services, or from other application ).Is There any direct solution for this without using
`String.Replace()` can u write the code to remove the commas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this works for me

```
string numb="2,50,000";
int.TryParse(numb, NumberStyles.AllowThousands, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat,out actualValue);
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:  (I haven't tested this at all)

```
string str = "RS.2,50,000";
str = str.substring(3, str.length);

string arr[] = str.split(",");

string newstr;
foreach (string s in arr)
{
    newstr += s;
}
```

Comment: OP seems to have blanks too... I'm not sure your code works... :)

Comment: should find out if OP actually has blanks or not?

Comment: if you look at the string in the first line of the post, it seems to be a blank. But this is just my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
string str = "25,000,000";
str = string.Join(string.Empty, str.Split(','));    
int i = Convert.ToInt32(str);
```

Comment: OP cannot use `String.Replace`

Comment: I was updating my answer but someone was so swift to downvote the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string rs = "Rs.2, 50,000";
string dst="";
foreach (char c in rs)
     if (char.IsDigit(c)) dst += c;
```

rs is source string, wihle in dst you have string you need.

Comment: @nawfal: OP asked a way to remove commas and did not mention the number has decimal part. So no,it won't work for 25000.34, but this is the answer to a different question ;) Thanks for the downvote :)

Comment: Agreed OP doesn't mention it, but a solution should be to handle the case, not the situation right? Please incorporate the warning in ur answer, I will cancel my downvote.

Comment: And do not mention about downvote in comments, it could be an impetus for others to downvote further :p

Comment: @nawfal: sorry, but I don't think I have to change my answer, not only for a downvote. I answered OP question 16 months ago. Not every answer should be valid for ALL situations you can find. And if you take a look at accepted answer, you'll find `int.TryParse`, demonstrating OP is parsing an int, not a float/double number.

Answer (score 1):

Something a little different:

```
        string rs = "Rs.2, 50,000";
        string s = String.Join("", Regex.Split(rs, @"[^\d]+"));
```